# Rotation calculation of an imbalanced object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, tensor-calculus, home-experiment, moment-of-inertia

Let's assume I have a scale like object hanging from a point. Now if I put an object inside it stays as it is, as we have replaced the spring with some sort of fabric, that doesn't expand itself.

Now, instead of putting the object in the center if I put the object in a little distance from the center, it will have some rotation, as it becomes imbalanced.

I want to know, how can I calculate those rotation, angular velocity, angular acceleration etc. Point of intersection is known, g is known, inertia tensor of every object is known, mass too.

Answer (score 0):

When  you are adding an extra mass its weight produces  a torque use the formula 
Torque= I× alpha to calculate angular acceleration 
Use mvr= I w for angular velocity